# Nominalisierung

Tags: nominalization

In dieser Frage muss ich Nominalisierung verwenden, wie soll ich das lösen?

> Zur Strategie gehört, Initiativen zur Steigerung der Nachfrage nach Sanitärleistung zu fördern und über Businessansätze zu stärken.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Welches Ziel soll erreicht werden? Ich lese: es muss (mehr) Nominalisierung eingesetzt werden. Ich lese: die soll in einer Frage geschehen. Ich übersehe: die Frage. Oder ist der Satz nach dem Fragezeichen gemeint?

Comment: Der Satz enthält bereits etliche Substantive - gibt es noch mehr Details, was nominalisiert werden soll?

Answer (score 1):

Zur Strategie gehört **die Förderung** von Initiativen zur *Nachfragesteigerung* nach Sanitärleistung und **deren Stärkung** über Businessansätze.

---

Die Nominalisierung macht hier durchaus Sinn. Das *zu...und zu...* ist etwas überladen. Das mit der Stärkung ist mir nur grammatikalisch klar.

---

*das Fördern* geht auch, nicht aber *deren Stärken*.